# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el input tenga un valor por defecto hasta que se cumpla el condicional?

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<b>¿Requiero folio de contra recibo?

<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="1" 
onchange="javascript:showContent()"/></b>
            <div id="content" style="display: none;">
                <label>Folio de contra recibo</label>
                <input type="text" name="ContraRecibo" class="form-control 
 input-sm">
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function showContent() {
                    element = document.getElementById("content");
                    check = document.getElementById("check");
                    if (check.checked) {
                        element.style.display = 'block';
                    } else {
                        element.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: Si te da algún error , o lo que pasa y esperas , actualiza la pregunta , te recomiendo realizar el [tour] y mirar [ask]

Comment: Podrías escribirlo directamente en el input `<input type="text" name="ContraRecibo" class="form-control input-sm" value"valorPorDefecto">`.

Comment: No esta claro lo que preguntas. Tu condicional sólo afecta a la visibilidad del input y preguntas por el valor que tiene asignado, creo que esperas que tenga un valor desde el principio, pero no se si quieres conservarlo si el elemento se hace visible o lo quieres borrar en ese caso.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showContent() {
            var element = document.getElementById("content"),
                check   = document.getElementById("check");


            if (check.checked) {
                element.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                element.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p><b>¿Requiero folio de contra recibo?</b>
    <input type="checkbox"
        name="check"
        id="check"
        value="1"
        onchange="showContent()"/></p>

    <div id="content" style="display: none;">
        <label>Folio de contra recibo</label>
        <input type="text"
            name="ContraRecibo"
            class="form-control input-sm"
            value="folio"> <!-- valor_por_defecto -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

He añadido un valor por defecto, puedes cambiarlo si haces visible el *input*. Sólo es necesario añadir la propiedad ***value*** en el *input*.